# Use htaccess to redirect users from http to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not at all familiar with htaccess. I need Htaccess code which will redirect http to https. I am using below code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But main problem is, I am getting below suggestion, when trying to test server speed:

```
To speed up page load times for visitors of your site, remove as many landing page
redirections as possible, and make any required redirections cacheable if possible.

http://xxxx.com/ is a non-cacheable redirect to https://xxxx.com/
```

So, how to make it cacheable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `http://xxxx.com/ is a non-cacheable redirect to https://xxxx.com/`

Errors says it all. To make it permanently cacheable in browser use `R=301`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```